Bound on condition number of k-LH (Local Hamiltonian) problem (a QMA complete problem)
Is the condition number of the matrix associated with the $k$-LH problem bounded? (where, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$).
For convenience, the definition of the k-LH problem is ( from paper [CM16], Definition-1 on page 2):
The (promise) problem $k$-local Hamiltonian is defined as follows.

We are given a $k$-local Hamiltonian $H$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{m} H^{(i)}$ on $n$ qubits with $m = \text{poly}(n)$. Each $H^{(i)}$ satisfies $||H^{(i)}|| = \text{poly}(n)$ and its entries are specified by $\text{poly}(n)$ bits. Where, $H\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ with $N\leq 2^n$.


We are also given two rational numbers $a < b$ of $\text{poly}(n)$ digits such that $b − a \geq 1/ poly(n)$, and promised that the
smallest eigenvalue of $H$ is either at most $a$, or at least $b$. Our task is to determine which of these two possibilities is the case.


My attempt: Condition number for normal matrices are given by $$\kappa(H)=\frac{\lambda_{\max}(H)}{\lambda_{\min}(H)}\,.$$
(i) I infer the promise gap ($b-a$) asserts a minimal gap between the two smallest eigenvalues of $H\in QMA$.
(ii) I infer the definition doesn't tell if all (successive and distinct) eigenvalues have a minimal gap. If $H$ has this property, one can roughly estimate how small the maximum eigenvalue could be if one knows the minimal eigenvalue. $\lambda_{\max}(H)> \lambda_{\min}(H) + \Delta N$, where $\Delta$ is the minimal possible gap between two distinct and successive eigenvalues of $H$, similar to eigen gap.
(ii) Also, one can construct an instance of k-LH where the minimal eigenvalue is zero. In such cases, the condition number diverges to infinity.
Based on the above statements, I conclude $k(H)$ is not bounded for all instances of the k-LH problem.

No.
With your definition of the conditioning number, you can get any value you want by just adding a constant to the ground state energy -- in fact, by making the ground state energy zero, the conditioning number diverges.
You can also get an arbitrarily small spectral gap: To this end, take any local Hamiltonian problem and add one extra qubit with a Hamiltonian $-\varepsilon \sigma_z$. Then, the spectral gap will be $\varepsilon$, which you can choose as small as you want, and which will not change the hardness of the ground state problem.
More generally, the point is that conditioning numbers for Hamiltonians are a somewhat useless concept, since the absolute energy
is not a meaningful concept -- energy differences are what matters, either differences between different eigenvalues of the same Hamiltonian, or differences in energies between related Hamiltonians (e.g., through the choice of some parameter).
